# Run posts_where and posts_join only on the main query

Tags: filters, wpdb, posts-where

Using the `pre_get_posts` hook, I'm able to take `$query` as an argument. But on `posts_where` and `posts_join` hook, I receive the respective clauses and not the query. The problem is that the hook is running on every query, not just the main one.

Given the following code, the code will be executed once on each query the page runs:

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'my_join');
function my_join($join) { echo 'lala'; return $join; }
```

How can I tell if the query is the main one so it only runs once?

Answer (score 3):

Of course! I just had to set the `$accepted_args` parameter of `add_filter()` to 2. Like so:

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'my_join', 10, 2);
function my_join($join, &$query) { echo $query->is_main_query() ? 'y' : 'n'; return $join; }
```